# Facebook app redirect always open in a new page outside of Facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect

I am making a little Facebook app that includes an image browser at the bottom, when the user clicks on one of the images in the browser I want to redirect the user to edit the image but stay inside the Facebook frame.  I am doing my redirect like this (I read on another page that this should work):

```
top.location.href = newUrl;
```

Sadly this just redirects to the newUrl outside of the Facebook frame, how can I make it do the redirect inside the Facebook frame?  A solution using Javascript would be the best but if I needed to make the call from php that could work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `self.location.href` instead.